# Calculate Space and Time complexity and Improve efficiency of this program

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

**Problem**

Find a  list of non repeating number in a array of repeating numbers.

**My Solution**

```
   public static int[] FindNonRepeatedNumber(int[] input)
    {
        List<int> nonRepeated = new List<int>();
        bool repeated = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            repeated = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((input[i] == input[j]) && (i != j))
                {
                    //this means the element is repeated.
                    repeated = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!repeated)
            {
                nonRepeated.Add(input[i]);
            }
        }

        return nonRepeated.ToArray();
    }
```

**Time and space complexity** 
Time complexity = O(n^2)
Space complexity = O(n)

I am not sure with the above calculated time complexity, also how can I make this program more efficient and fast.

Comment: Are you at the interview right now? :D

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the actual question you are asking?

Comment: To be clear: Is this C++? Does it have to be in C++ or can it be in any language or in pseudo-code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I am actually preparing for one

Comment: @jsalonen I want to know how to make this program more efficient and are my calculated complexities correct ?

Comment: I don't actually understand the interview question.  Is this how it was posed to you?  If you have a better explanation, include it in your question.

Comment: The time complexity for the algorithm you have written is O(n^2) if n is the number of elements in the array. The worst case is when all of the elements are unique. It's kind of hard to help you beyond that. It's really hard to understand what exactly you are asking, and your code doesn't seem to match your problem statement (at the very least, it isn't literally taking two arrays as input).

Comment: yes, this is from the placement paper I searched on the internet

Comment: Then provide a link to the placement paper.

Comment: I am sorry I had posted the wrong question, I have corrected it now. Link to the paper http://blog.sanaulla.info/2009/11/26/my-placement-saga-1-directi/ question no 3

Comment: @nikhil what do you mean by that... 'Set' has many meanings can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of the Algorithm you provided is `O(n^2)`.

Use Hashmaps to improve the algorithm. The Psuedo code is as follows:

```
public static int[] FindNonRepeatedNumbers(int[] A)
{
Hashtable<int, int> testMap= new Hashtable<int, int>();

for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
            tmp=testMap.get(A[i]);
            testMap.put(A[i],tmp+1);
}

/* Elements that are not repeated are:

Set set = teatMap.entrySet(); 
// Get an iterator 
Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
// Display elements 
while(i.hasNext()) { 
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
if(me.getValue() >1)
{
    System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
}
}
```

**Operation:**
What I did here is I used Hashmaps with **keys** to the hashmaps being the elements of the input array. The **values** for the hashmaps are like counters for each element. So if an element occurs once then the value for that key is 1 and the key value is subsequently incremented based on recurrence of element in input array.

So finally you just check your hashmap and then display elements with hashvalue 1 which are non-repated elements. The time complexity for this algorithm is `O(k)` for creating hashmap and `O(k)` for searching, if the input array length is `k`. This is much faster than `O(n^2)`. The worst case is when there are no repeated elements at all. The psuedo code might be messy but this approach is the best way I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity O(n) means you can't have an inner loop. A full inner loop is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

two pointers. begining and end. increment begining when same letters reached and store the start and end pos ,length for reference...  increment end otherwise.. keep doing this til end of list..compare all the outputs and you should have the longest continuous list of unique numbers. I hope this is what the question required. Linear algo.

```
void longestcontinuousunique(int arr[])
{
int start=0;
int end =0;
while (end! =arr.length())
{
if(arr[start] == arr[end])
{
start++;
savetolist(start,end,end-start);
}
else
end++
}

return maxelementof(savedlist);
    }
```

Comment: in case you want the first list.. just output it as soon as you find one.